# Why two curves instead of one?

Tags: matplotlib

I am aiming to generate a plot of Y vs. X. Instead what I get is plot for X and a plot Y  when i run the following:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
X = [x for x in np.arange(.8, 1.2, .05)]
Y = [getm(v) for v in X]
plt.plot(X, Y, '-o')
plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Y')
plt.grid()
plt.savefig('test.png')
plt.show()
```

What is wrong with my script?

Comment: What is getm(v)? If the output of getm(v) is a list of size 2, then plot(X,Y) will have two lines instead of 1.

Comment: True, I failed to check the size of the list. Thanks.

Comment: The line 

    X = [x for x in np.arange(.8, 1.2, .05)]

Is redundant and can simply be written as:

    X = np.arange(.8, 1.2, .05)

Answer (score 0):

The result of your function getm must be more than one value. I used the following code to verify:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy

x = numpy.arange(0.8, 1.2, 0.05)
y1 = [x_val**2 for x_val in x]
y2 = [ [x_val**2, x_val**3] for x_val in x]
y3 = [ [x_val**2] for x_val in x]

plt.subplot(131)
plt.plot(x, y1)
plt.subplot(132)
plt.plot(x, y2)
plt.subplot(133)
plt.plot(x, y3)

plt.show()
```

And the result looks like:
[image]